# Performance benefit java.util.Date compareTo vs before/after?

Tags: java, date, comparison

The title is pretty self explanatory but I wanted to know if there is any performance benefit to using

```
date1.compareTo(date2) < 0
```

instead of

```
date1.before(date2)
```

or

```
date2.after(date1)
```

in Java 7?

Comment: There isn't. They both retrieve their millisecond values and compare those.

Comment: For "performance"-related questions, first [apply the concepts of these quotes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#Quotes). Then if there is a "performance" issue, explain *what* it is (or why it is perceived to be) in the question. If there is no identified issue there is no pertinent question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

compareTo is slightly slower as it needs to return three possible results. Before and after is a simpler calculation.
However, the best reason to use them is that they are clearer.